# Why does Google Scholar provide a different number of references when sorting by relevance versus date?

Tags: google-scholar

I've noticed that sorting by date, and relevance has different numbers of results.  Why is this?

**Edit**: Here is a reproducible example:

Here is "foo" sorted by date (15,000 references)

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?scisbd=2&q=foo&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

[image]
[image]

Here is "foo" sorted by relevance (300,000 references)

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=foo

[image][image]

Comment: Which aspect of Google Scholar are you seeing this behavior in? I can't figure out which piece of the UI you are talking about.

Comment: I edited to provide example

Comment: Thanks for the revision, it's a more complete question now.

Answer (score 6):

(I'll repeat an [earlier answer of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/21298/4140), which is relevant here, although the [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21295/4140) is not a duplicate. Nevertheless, the question itself is relevant. *Why* are you interested in *how many* Google Scholar results a particular search yields in the first place?)

The "approximate" ("about") number of hits Google reports is *completely* worthless - in *all* Google searches. To see why, look at this number on both the first and the tenth page of Google hits:

[First results page](https://www.google.com/#q=%22Stack+Exchange%22)

[Tenth results page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Stack+Exchange%22&start=90)

When I just did this, I got "approximately 15,200,000 hits" reported on the first results page... but only "approximately 96 hits" on the tenth page.

Given the opacity of Google's search algorithms, which likely have a lot of sampling built in, it's not overly surprising to me that you get surprising results even if you only sort your results in a different way.

In addition, your results will probably vary depending on your [search engine bubble](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=search%20engine%20bubble) (another reason why this number is useless).

Comment: Note: if you click "repeat the search with the omitted results included" on page 10, and page 1 and page 10 both say "about 15,500,000 results." (I don't know how many pages it says this for--at least to page 22.)

Comment: I'm looking at about 20 to a couple as there's only a couple dozen cites, to begin from based upon the original paper on the topic.